# Apply dictionarry to text file

Tags: text-editors, text-editing, dictionary

I have dictionary that contains of approx. 100 lines

```
word_1 transalted_word_1
...
word_n transalted_word_n
```

I need to translate several txt files (actually these files are XML) in most automated way. What is the best way to do that? Maybe some magic plugin available for notepad++?

Answer (score 0):

[Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/)

Cute and paste your words into Google Translate. Choose the Detect (from) language, and set the Translate (to) language. It will translate up to n-words. Then you can copy them once they are translated.

Otherwise you'd have to pay for a document translation. Or you can write your own program which would be free. Any free translation sites or programs are minimal.

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question. He already has the translated words and want to apply them to a file. Google translate will not do that.